# Does association rule learning require a minimum size data set and if so why?

Tags: machine-learning

I have been experimenting with the typical grocery store tutorial examples for [Association Rule Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) in R. The data set I am given is around ~9,800 entries and the algorithms seem to work well for a data set given of this size.

I am considering applying the algorithms to a project I'm working on and I was wondering if there is a minimum size data set (aside from the trivial notion you need at least one entry) that is required in order for the algorithm to yield results.

## My Question

Does association rule learning require a minimum size data set and if so why?

Answer (score 0):

Well, to get any result at all, you do need at least 1 example. After that, the question becomes: how complex/rare are the relations that you want to learn? More complex/rare relations require more data. You can't learn that a certain relation occurs 1 every 1000 examples, if you only have 100 examples.
I'm not sure if there are theorems or rules of thumb regarding a minimum number of examples necessary to confidently predict a given 'complexity of rules'.